# How to convert IP Version 6 into string? What should I use instead of 0xFF in case for ipv6?

Tags: string, ip, ipv6, ipv4

This is how you would convert a 32 bit integer ipv4;

```
int e = 12345678;
u_char ip[4];
ip[0] = ip & 0xFF;
ip[1] = (ip >> 8) & 0xFF;
ip[2] = (ip >> 16) & 0xFF;
ip[3] = (ip >> 24) & 0xFF;
printf("\t%d.%d.%d.%d\n", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
```

How can I convert ipv6 to dotted string? What instead of 0xFF? PLEASE HELP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion IPv6 to long and long to IPv6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875728/conversion-ipv6-to-long-and-long-to-ipv6)

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all: IPv6 doesn't use dots (except when representing an embedded IPv4 address) but colons.

And representing an IPv6 address in its [recommended canonical representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952) isn't that easy either. I would recommend just using [inet_ntop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_ntop.html) to convert from numerical to printable format.